# How to check two different column values

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have the following table

```
Name Salary Grade
AA    10000  1
A      8000  1
B     11000  2
```

I want to extract the records where Name starts with 'A' and salary > 10000

I tried to solve first part by the use of regular expression as ^A along with the Name as the criterion to be matched in 'advance filters' under 'Data' tab in libreoffice-calc. However, I am getting blank rows as output.

I need help regarding the testing of such two conditions.

Comment: There is no row where "Name" begins with "A" and "Salary" is greater than `10000`. So your filter seems to work just right.

Comment: Under Name, there are two names starting with 'A'...AA and A

Comment: Yes, and none of them have a salary greater than `10000`. That leaves no rows matching the criteria...

Comment: I am checking only the first condition. However, I need to check both conditions to get the final output.

Comment: Then you could just use a "Standard Filter" with "Name" "Begins with" "A".

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using "Standard Filter" I checked both the conditions and got the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment by @stickybit:

> Use a "Standard Filter" with "Name" "Begins with" "A".